# Macbook (12' 2015) keyboard and trackpad

Tags: 16.04, drivers, keyboard, touchpad, macbook

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a Macbook 2015 (not Pro). Laptop keyboard and trackpad are not working (except power button). I have installed  [macbook12-spi-driver](https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver) from GitHub, but it still do not work.

I have no idea what else to try or commands to run to to make changes.

Hope someone managed to make Ubuntu (or an alternative distro work on a Macbook).

**EDIT**

Here is print of cat /etc/initramfs-tools/modules

```
# List of modules that you want to include in your initramfs.
# They will be loaded at boot time in the order below.
#
# Syntax:  module_name [args ...]
#
# You must run update-initramfs(8) to effect this change.
#
# Examples:
#
# raid1
# sd_mod

# applespi
applespi
spi_pxa2xx_platform
spi_pxa2xx_pci

# applespi
applespi
spi_pxa2xx_platform
intel_lpss_pci
```

I think there are two groups of applespi, because I tried both installations methods listed in on GitHub for the macbook12-spi-driver (link above).

Comment: Please [edit] the output of  `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/modules` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing linux kernel version 4.14 solved the problem (I wasn't aware that Ubuntu 16.04 used an earlier kernel).

Now keyboard and touchpad works.

I have not yet fully tested all special keys, but things like volume control and keyboard light works fine.